# How can I query multiple fields in a Mongoose $elemMatch

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have a data model that records an array of activities on my record, including logging any issues and errors:

```
activities?: {
  message?: string;
  data?: any;
  issue?: {
    errors?: AVError[];
    dismissed?: {
      timestamp: string;
      message?: string;
    };
  }
}[];
```

I need to run a query that finds all records that do not have any activities that have an issue that is not dismissed (i.e. `dismissed` does not exist).

Everything I have tried seems to fail on some point. This is the most recent query I have tried:

```
collection.find({
  activities: {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        issue: { $exists: true },
        'issue.dismissed': { $exists: false },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This works when the issue does not exist or when issue.dismissed does not exist, but it still doesn't seem to recognize when the issue.dismissed does exist.

I have also tried this:

```
collection.find({
    $or: [
      { 'activities.issue': { $exists: false } },
      {
        'activities.issue': { $exists: true },
        'activities.issue.dismissed': { $exists: true },
      },
    ],
});
```

But this also did not return some records that were dismissed.

As a workaround I can return all data and then manually filter the data, but I expect there is a way to do this in one Mongoose query.

Comment: I've read your question "*I need to run a query that finds all records that do not have any activities that have an issue that is not dismissed (i.e. dismissed does not exist).*" about 10 tens and can't understand what you actually need. Can you add some sample documents and what you expect the outcome of the query to be against those documents i.e. which documents should be returned from the query please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understood what are you looking for but I understand:

> I need to run a query that finds all records that do not have any activities that have an issue that is not dismissed (i.e. dismissed does not exist).

As:

> I want only elements where all values into `activities` have an `issue`.

So "do not have any activities with an issue not dismissed" is like "no activities with unresolved issues" so "all returned activities have all issues dismissed".

So I think your query is almost what you want. I've tried this query and fits in what I've understood:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "activities": {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        "issue.dismissed": {
          $exists: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-LdIwxSYm5r).

In this example I've added five documents and the only returned are those which all `activities` have an `issue`. And also return elements with no `activities` because I think is what ou want using the `{ 'activities.issue': { $exists: false } },` into the `$or` query. By the way if you don't want that value try [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MPimytevkyx) instead.

The difference with your query is you have added `issue: { $exists: true },` so values with `activities` but without `issues` are returned too.